# How to jQuery show element fast while hide with small duration

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I in jQuery toggle element on faster than toggle this element off in miliseconds?

There is my code:

````
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.enmenu').on('click', function(){
        $('.ensettings').fadeToggle();
        return false;
    });

    $('html, body').on('click',function(){
        $('.ensettings').hide();
    });

    $(".ensettings").click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
/* Dropdown menu - End */```
````

Comment: You can specify the duration in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fadeToggle` conditionally to set the speed of the toggle.

```
$('.enmenu').on('click', function() {

  var el = $('.ensettings');
  el.fadeToggle(el.is(":hidden") ? 200 : 5000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `fadeToggle`, simply use `hide` or `show` with the duration parameter set. To know if an element is hidden or not, use `is(":hidden")`:

```
$('.enmenu').on('click', function(){
    var $elem = $('.ensettings');

    if($elem.is(":hidden")) {             // if element is hidden
        $elem.show(200);                  // show with 200 miliseconds animation
    } else {                              // otherwise
        $elem.hide(5000);                 // hide with 5000 miliseconds animation
    }

    return false;
});
```